# error the application stopped when press mobile logout button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I have **Android** app which play sound and when I want to **log off** from the app as when press on mobile **logout** button i have the error message " **the application stopped ...**" .

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

         super.onStop(); 

    if(mp.isPlaying())
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
      finish();
      }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();


    if(mp!=null)
    {


         if(mp.isPlaying())

      mp.stop();
         mp.release();


    }
    finish();

}
```

> 06-30 00:09:48.403: I/Choreographer(678): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   06-30 00:09:48.452: D/gralloc_goldfish(678): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   06-30 00:09:49.761: I/Choreographer(678): Skipped 135 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   06-30 00:09:51.331: D/dalvikvm(678): GC_CONCURRENT freed 82K, 2% free 8378K/8519K, paused 123ms+21ms, total 278ms
>   06-30 00:10:18.202: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(678): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>   06-30 00:10:19.042: D/AndroidRuntime(678): Shutting down VM
>   06-30 00:10:19.042: W/dalvikvm(678): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan} did not call through to super.onStop()
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5148)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3232)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3291)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   06-30 00:10:19.211: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Every time a develper sees "the application stopped..." it should be read as "Look in Logcat". Logcat will provide you with details why the application crashed, and even what line caused the crash. If you use Eclipse, then go to `Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat`, to add it.

Answer (score 1):

It throws a `SuperNotCalledException` in `onStop()` which means you did not called `super.onStop()`:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
  super.onStop(); // must be called.
}
```

Every method from the activity lify cycle, such as `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()`, etc, should call the super methods.

Comment: when I modfied the code to protected void onStop() { super.onStop(); if(mp!=null)
    {
          

    if(mp.isPlaying())
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
      finish();

    }  the sound doesnot stopped